# Aligning equal signs in equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

Up to now, I use the `align` environment. As I want to give each equation a specific reference number, I want to use the `equation` environment. So I tried this, which works for `align`:

```
\begin{equation}
x &=2 \\
&=1+1
\end{equation}
```

But this throws errors. Why doesn't it work?

Of course, I've searched for similar questions but there was no question out there, that handles specific this issue. (It was always very complex code; **no minimal example**)

Comment: `equation` cannot be split accross lines by design.  That is why we have `align` and others, for example `split`. Why do you want to go to `equation`?

Comment: `align` number each line of equations! you should make effort to skip this nubering, so I do not understand your question

Comment: If you want only one number for the whole thing I would suggest sticking `\nonumber` at the end of lines you don't want numbered. There may also be a way to use `align*` and tell LaTeX to make an exception for the lines you want numbered.

Comment: within `equation` you could use the `split` environment, which aligns the = signs but results in only one number.  see that `amsmath` documentation: `texdoc amsmath`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, the answer is trivial and has already been given in the comments, but since you insist on asking for a **minimal working example** (boldfaced :-), here it is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Text before the equation.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        x &= 2 \\
          &= 1+1
    \end{split}
    \label{eq:x=2=1+1}
\end{equation}
Text after equation~\eqref{eq:x=2=1+1}, with a reference to the equation itself.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot understand why this trivial answer got so many upvotes (or rather, any upvote at all! :-)

Comment: If you insist, I can downvote… ;o)

Comment: @Bernard: Well, I guess that, after all, this is sort of a compensation for other situations in which you write a pretty deep answer to some though question, and you get just one upvote… ;-)

Comment: This has been reported by many. The simple and obvious solutions get upvotes. If you want to gain rep quickly, don't spend more than five minutes on an answer.

Comment: I searched for "aligning equal sign in equations" in the TeX.SE search bar and got exactly what I (as a novice user) needed. As they say, SE helps future visitors, too! :o)